# Group select options if description is the same

Tags: laravel

So I have a select that the options are froma laravel Foreach

```
@foreach($courseMonth as $cm)->groupBy('description');
    <optgroup label="{{ nameMonth($cm->month) }}">
        @foreach($days as $date)
            @if(date('m', strtotime($date['date'])) == $cm->month)
                <option value="{{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date['date'])) ." - ". $date['hours'] }}">{{ $date['description'] . ' - ' . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date['date'])) . ' - ' . $date['hours'] . ' ('. $date['total'] . 'h)'}}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </optgroup>
    <?php $i++;?>
@endforeach
```

This is the options. And I want if `$date['description']` is the same in two options, to combine both options. More detailed, if three options have their description as "Work", to combine all of the options.
I've tried a groupby in front of the foreach

```
@foreach($courseMonth as $cm)->groupBy('description');
```

But this didn't do anything. The table for the options only has one row (ex: One row has only one description but it can have multiple day options in the select) so I need to group those only when there is the same description in two options.

Table structure:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id | description | date     | hours | total |
|---------------------------------------------|
| 4  |    work     |2019-23-4 | 14h   | 6h    |
| 5  |    work     |2019-23-5 | 13h   | 5h    |
| 6  |    school   |2019-23-5 | 13h   | 5h    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

So the first two would appear in the same option and the last one as the second option of the select.

Comment: Please add table structure with some dummy data if possible

Comment: Added the table

Comment: Should `@foreach($courseMonth as $cm)->groupBy('description');` not be `@foreach($courseMonth->groupBy('description') as $cm)`? And of course, that is assuming `$courseMonth` is a `QueryBuilder`, and not a `Collection`. If it is a `Collection`, then please show your controller-function with every model involved to get the `$courseMonth` assembled.